# Linq2Sql Clone an Object C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, clone

```
tblAgreement AgreementOld = (from g in TDC.tblAgreements
                             where g.AccountID == ids.accountID && g.AgreementID == AgreementID
                            select g).SingleOrDefault();

Guid AgreementIDNew = Guid.NewGuid();
var AgreementNew = AgreementOld;
AgreementNew.AgreementID = AgreementIDNew;
AgreementNew.StatusChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
AgreementNew.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
AgreementNew.AccountID = ids.accountID;
AgreementNew.CreatedByID = ids.userID;
TDC.tblAgreements.InsertOnSubmit(AgreementNew);
```

I am trying to create a new object  with some same values as old object, But i am getting this error message;

> *Cannot add an entity that already exists.*

Note: I don't want to delete OLD object. Kindly Help me I have google it but couldn't find any help or solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new object, currently your new object is also reffering to old one:

```
var AgreementNew = new Agreement();  // create a new instance
AgreementNew.SomeProperty = AgreementOld.SomeProperty; // assign property from old to new
AgreementNew.AgreementID = AgreementIDNew; // new proerties here
AgreementNew.StatusChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
AgreementNew.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
AgreementNew.AccountID = ids.accountID;
AgreementNew.CreatedByID = ids.userID;
TDC.tblAgreements.InsertOnSubmit(AgreementNew);
```

Comment: I know this solution but its so headaching!

Comment: @WaqarAhmed you have to do this way, its reference type so that way won't work what you want

Answer (score 0):

If AgreementOld is DataTable then just do

```
var AgreementNew = AgreementOld.Copy();
```